# Python Logging - Logger erroneously gets imported to another file

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I have two python scripts(test1.py, test2.py) which initialize their own loggers. test2.py imports a single variable from test1.py. Strangely though, the logger from test1.py also gets automatically imported into test2.py.

**test1.py**

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

LOG_FILENAME = '1.log'
rootLogger = logging.getLogger("default")
rootLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Set up a specific logger with our desired output level
consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
rootLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

# Add the log message handler to the logger
handler = logging.FileHandler( LOG_FILENAME)
rootLogger.addHandler(handler)

a = 1
b = 2
```

**test2.py**

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

LOG_FILENAME = '2.log'
rootLogger = logging.getLogger("default")
rootLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Set up a specific logger with our desired output level
consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
rootLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

# Add the log message handler to the logger
handler = logging.FileHandler( LOG_FILENAME)
rootLogger.addHandler(handler)


a = 3
from test1 import b
rootLogger.debug("a:%s",a)
rootLogger.debug("b:%s",b)
```

Now when I run test2.py, I expect that only the rootLogger from test2.py should be called. More importantly, I expected that only `2.log` will be written to. But strangely, apart from duplicate output on console, `1.log` also gets generated.

```
$ python test2.py 
a:3
a:3
b:2
b:2

$ cat 1.log 
a:3
b:2
```

Why is this happening, and what is the best practice to avoid such scenarios.

**Update**

I changed the getLogger call to differentiate different loggers.

```
rootLogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

But even then, "1.log" file gets created, but this time it remains empty.

I understand that I should ideally not declare rootLogger as a global, but then I will have to pass rootLogger handler to all the function calls.

Comment: You are aware that when you import anything from a module, even if it is a single variable, **all** the module level code is executed?

Comment: What exactly you have done by this - "I changed the getLogger call to differentiate different loggers."

Comment: You can see the code in the question itself. Here `rootLogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`

Comment: what is the value of `__name__` for both cases ?

Comment: Within a module, the module’s name (as a string) is available as the value of the global variable `__name__`.  https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few comments later(thanks @schwobaseggl), I realized the obvious issue. The problem I faced was a combination of two concepts:

1. When you import anything from a module, even if it is a single variable, all the module level code is executed.
2. Multiple calls to getLogger() with the same name will always return a reference to the same Logger object. https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

So basically, since I was using the same logger name in both the scripts, and the `global module code` from both was getting run, sequentially, I accidentally added different FileHandler twice on the same logger.

**Solution**

Always place the logger initialization code in `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

a = 1
b = 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LOG_FILENAME = '1.log'
    rootLogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    rootLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Set up a specific logger with our desired output level
    consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    rootLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

# Add the log message handler to the logger
    handler = logging.FileHandler( LOG_FILENAME)
    rootLogger.addHandler(handler)
```